# Deleting Windows Temp Files using python script

Tags: python, subprocess, python-import, delete-file, rmdir

Can you help me how can i delete all the files under the Windows/Temp files??
Below are my scripts but it doesn't work at all.

```
import os
import subprocess
recPath = 'C:\\Windows\\Temp'
ls = []
if os.path.exists(recPath):
    for i in os.listdir(recPath):
        ls.append(os.path.join(recPath, i))
else:
    print 'Please provide valid path!'

paths = ' '.join(ls)
pObj = subprocess.Popen('rmdir C:\\Windows\\Temp\\*.* /s /q *.*'+paths, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE)
rTup = pObj.communicate()
rCod = pObj.returncode
if rCod == 0:
    print 'Success: Cleaned Windows Temp Folder'
else:
    print 'Fail: Unable to Clean Windows Temp Folder'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what means `doesn't work` ? We can't read in your mind. Do you get error message ? Always show full message in question.

Comment: hi. apologies for the confusion. btw, there's no error message display after i execute in the command.

Comment: rmdir is mean for remove directory, you might wanna try with command del instead, also you might not need the paths since you plan to remove all files, try 'del C:\\Windows\\Temp\\*.* /s /q '

Comment: print full line `rmdir ...` and try it in command. print variables to see what you get.

Comment: `*.*'+paths` this doesn't add space between `*.*` and paths

Comment: hi Skycc. thank you for suggesting but can you please give me a sample code on how to use it. Sorry but im a newbie in using python language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using windows command del to remove all files in dir with wildcard
. This will delete all files recursively within it, however it will leave the empty subfolder there

```
import os, subprocess
del_dir = r'c:\windows\temp'
pObj = subprocess.Popen('del /S /Q /F %s\\*.*' % del_dir, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE)
rTup = pObj.communicate()
rCod = pObj.returncode
if rCod == 0:
    print 'Success: Cleaned Windows Temp Folder'
else:
    print 'Fail: Unable to Clean Windows Temp Folder'
```

change the 1st line to below to delete whole directory tree of Windows\Temp.This will remove everything include the Temp folder itself if success, recreate parent directory afterwards

```
del_dir = r'c:\windows\temp'
pObj = subprocess.Popen('rmdir /S /Q %s' % del_dir, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE)
# recreate the deleted parent dir in case it get deleted
os.makedirs(del_dir)
```

Else, rmtree from shutil should be a pretty good choice, ignore_errors set to ignore all the errors in middle and continue until all directory tree complete

```
import shutil, os
del_dir = r'c:\windows\temp'
shutil.rmtree(del_dir, ignore_errors=True)
# recreate the deleted parent dir in case it get deleted
os.makedirs(del_dir)
```

Another option to iterate over directory to be deleted

```
import os,shutil
del_dir = r'c:\windows\temp'
for f in os.listdir(del_dir):
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        os.remove(f)
    elif os.path.isdir(f)
        shutil.rmtree(f, ignore_errors=True)
```

change the del_dir accordingly to any directory of interest

*You are dealing with windows folder, beware to set the directory to delete carefully, you would not want to mistakenly put del_dir = r'c:\windows'*

Comment: hi Skycc. Thanks man for the code. However it didn't delete all the folders and subfolders on the Windows\Temp.

Comment: try the rmdir cmd i just added, actually the shutil cmd with ignore_errors set to True should works, it will try to delete what ever it can delete included empty subfolder leaving those fail to delete behind

Comment: Hi Skycc. I tried to apply that code to delete the Prefetch folder under C:\Windows. The good news is it delete everything on the prefetch folder but the bad news is it also deleted the Prefetch folder. How can i prevent to do not delete the Prefetch folder.

Comment: Not a very good answer, after deleting, recreate the folder with os.makedirs(r'c:\windows\prefetch') or use os.listdir(r'c:\windows\prefetch') then use os.remove(file) if its a file else use shutil.rmtree(dir) for dir

Comment: How can i apply that script to my actual script bro? Can you help me?

Comment: Checkout added answer bro :)

Comment: Sure thing bro. Thanks. :)

Comment: Hi Skycc. Upon trying the updated scripts. Still it delete the Temp Folder and didnt create as expected. I think because the scripts needs an admin privilege to create a directory on Windows. How can we create a script with an admin privilege?

Comment: Weird, when you run the script as admin, when you able to delete, you should be able to create, how about trying the last solution i provide that iterate though directory, that doesn't remove the source dir

Comment: Or you could try os.system('mkdir %s' % del_dir) instead of os.makedirs

Comment: can you please check my other concerns bro?? here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40560050/disk-defrag-and-disk-clean-up-using-python-script

Comment: Great, sure, will check when free

Comment: there's a typo in the 4th solution (removing files and subfolders with python) : the `else` condition is missing a semicolon

Answer (score 1):

Use [shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html).

```
import shutil

shutil.rmtree(r"C:\Windows\Temp")
```

Comment: hi Batman. thank you for your help. upon trying the code that you gave. it deleted some files but not all the files and folders in the windows\temp folder.

Comment: Weird. What happens if you call `os.unlink(path)` on one of the remaining files?

Comment: i guess you don't have permission to remove all files in temp, some might be in use. Try if you are able to remove that manually

Comment: hi Batman. it didn't do anything when i used the os.unlink(path).

Comment: I'm going to guess that they're in use then. Try rebooting the machine and see if they're removable afterwards.

Comment: try goto temp dir, right click delete any of files that fail to delete see if you were able to do that, if it fail, script method will fail also

Comment: hi skycc. upon trying it manually, there are some files that fail to delete. can you please help to delete  all the files including the folders ans sub folders and ignore all the files/folders that fail to delete??

Answer (score 0):

You might want to hard-code the path.

```
    import os
    import shutil
    del_dir = r'C:\Windows\Temp'
    for f in os.listdir(del_dir):
        if os.path.isfile(r'C:\Windows\Temp\\'+f):
            os.remove(r'C:\Windows\Temp\\'+f)
        elif os.path.isdir(r'C:\Windows\Temp\\'+f):
            shutil.rmtree(r'C:\Windows\Temp\\'+f, ignore_errors=True)
```